# Sum javascript arrays repeated value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sum repeated javascript arrays value and I want to every key has one value after this sum.

Here is javascript array example:

```
var myArray = [ {'TR-01':1}, {'TR-02':3}, {'TR-01':3}, {'TR-02':5}];
```

Desired Formatted Array Should Like This:

```
var newArray = [ {'TR-01':4}, {'TR-02':8}];
```

How can we do this in javascript?

Comment: avoid using identical keys in objects !

Comment: Objects in javascript can not contain more then one time of each key. To this end use an array.

Comment: @kodcu, Is it possible for you to work with another structure such as array of objects? `var obj = [ {'TR-01':1},
            {'TR-02':3}, 
            {'TR-01':3},
            {'TR-02':5} 
    ];`

Comment: yes :) Sorry For My Mistake

Comment: Why are you using the same key more that one time, in Javascript the object cannot have identical keys, it will rewrite by the last value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
var obj = {
    'TR-01':1,
    'TR-02':3, 
    'TR-01':3,
    'TR-02':5 
};
```

If you do an `alert(obj["TR-01"]);` now, you can see that the output is `3`.

Or a `console.log(obj)`, the output is: `{TR-01: 3, TR-02: 5}`. You don't know the previous values.

You essentially overwritten them. I'd say you can't do this. At least not the way you imagined.

**Update**

```
var myArray = [ 
    {'TR-01':1}, 
    {'TR-02':3}, 
    {'TR-01':3}, 
    {'TR-02':5} 
];

var newArray = [];
var newObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for(var prop in myArray[i]) {
      if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          newObj[prop] = 0;
      }
      newObj[prop] += myArray[i][prop];
  }
}

for(var prop in newObj) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[prop] = newObj[prop];
    newArray.push(obj);
}

console.log(newObj);    // OUTPUT: {TR-01: 4, TR-02: 8}
console.log(newArray);  // OUTPUT: [ { TR-01: 4 }, { TR-02: 8 } ]
```

I'm sure there are easier ways, I am still just learning JS as well. :)

Comment: Maybe we can create a new object with summed value.I have a like this object and keys repeated...

Answer (score 0):

Flexible solution with `Array.map()` and `Object.keys()`:

```
var myArray = [ 
            {'TR-01':1},
            {'TR-02':3}, 
            {'TR-01':3},
            {'TR-02':5} 
    ];

    var summedArray = [], props = {}, prop;

    myArray.map(function(obj){
        var prop = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // get single object property name
        props[prop] = (Object.keys(props).indexOf(prop) !== -1)?  (props[prop] + obj[prop]) : obj[prop];
    });
    for (prop in props) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[prop] = props[prop];
        summedArray.push(newObj); // adding object to final array
    }
    console.log(summedArray); // [{'TR-01':4}, {'TR-02':8}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary object with an object for the reference and an array for the result:

```js
var myArray = [{ 'TR-01': 1 }, { 'TR-02': 3 }, { 'TR-01': 3 }, { 'TR-02': 5 }],
    result = myArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
        Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
            var o = {};
            if (!(k in r.obj)) {
                o[k] = 0;
                r.obj[k] = o;
                r.array.push(o);
            }
            r.obj[k][k] += a[k];
        });
        return r;
    }, { array: [], obj: {} }).array;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```